# SSRS: How to display repeated item

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can I achieve something like this?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ut67ZHpdFdX2VNT3RVaTA2d1E/edit?usp=sharing

This is the record sample:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Ut67ZHpdFdS2drRm9WWWJFMlk/edit?usp=sharing

I able to do it if using normal programming language.
I'm still new to SSRS, and I'm not sure how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "list" data region as described [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239330%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Group the data by "store", and you should be in business.

Edit: this isn't precisely what the poster is looking for, and what he/she wants to do is trivial in SSRS 08 R2, but generates build errors when I try to do it in 2008 compatibility mode.

Comment: If I group it by store, then I need to have aggregate function for the remaining column right?

Comment: It appears I was wrong, as tables are not allowed to be child items of lists.  I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: i able to do it suprisingly. just that I need to modify my query: select a,b,c,d from Table group by a,b,c,d .. i missed out the group by..

Comment: Heh, I was in the middle of a screenshot walkthrough for doing it in SSRS.  I'm glad you solved it, though.